# Leasing doesn't work in ejabberd

Tags: ejabberd

how can I turn on XEP-0060 12.18 Time-Based Subscriptions (Leases) in ejabberd?
I think source code for that behavior is in pubsub_subscription.erl I tried it with psi and it doesn't work (I send 'set' stanza with 2006-02-28T11:59Z and get type='result' but when I send 'get' according 12.18 I dont get it back)

Comment: and subscription doesn't go away even though I set pubsub#expire to 2006 year